# How to get woocommerce product title inside contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

I have set a website with "Contact Form 7" and "Woo Commerce" and in the shop page where all the products are displayed I have managed to add a button with the following code "Download Brochure":

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'rox_loop_download_button', 5);
function rox_loop_download_button() {
global $product;
$product_id = $product->get_id();
 { ?>
        <div class="button-pdb">
<a href="">download brochure</a></div>
<?php }
}
```

Now i want when a user send the inquery form to take the name of the product by default.

I have tried the following code but it seems to work only on the product single page : `functions.php`

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'product_enquiry_tab' );
    function product_enquiry_tab( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Enquire about Product', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'product_enquiry_tab_form'
    );

    return $tabs;

}
function product_enquiry_tab_form() {
    global $product;
    //If you want to have product ID also
    //$product_id = $product->id;
    $subject    =   "Enquire about ".$product->post->post_title;

    echo "<h3>".$subject."</h3>";
    echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="19" title="Contact form 1_copy"]'); //add your contact form shortcode here ..

    ?>

    <script>
    (function($){
        $(".product_name").val("<?php echo $subject; ?>");
    })(jQuery);
    </script>   
    <?php   
}
    ?>
```

And the code for the "contact form 7" :

```
<p>Your Name (required)<br />
        [text* your-name] </p>

    <p>Your Email (required)<br />
        [email* your-email] </p>

    <p class="product_subject">Subject<br />
        [text your-subject class:product_name] </p>

    <p>Your Message<br />
        [textarea your-message] </p>

    <p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNzeV.jpg

Comment: what is an exactly you need?

Comment: On the shop page when you display all the products I have added a button “download” and linked the button with CF7 and when the form is submitted i want the form to display the product name on the email that i have got

Comment: You can use `jQuery` to get this done. Use a hidden form field and set the title to the particular field. Then you can set that value from the `Mail Config`.

Comment: on one page i have multiple products displayed and i use one button and one contact form and if i do [_post_title] or [_post_url] it will give me the url or name of the page and not the name of the product which the form was subbmited from
I am using this on the shop page not on product single page

Answer (score 2):

I am using this one of my websites. I don't need another plugin nor JavaScript, I just send the Woocommerce product title as GET parameter to the contact form page.
See https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/

**Step 1**

Send the product title to the contact form.
In my theme sub directory woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php I changed the add-to-cart button into a request button. The product ID and the product title are added to the URL as URL parameters. Important: the 'name' attribute needs to be the same as a field configured in the contact form.

```
<button type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>"
        class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo _e( 'Request', 'framework' ); ?></button>
<input type="hidden" name="product-id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="contact-subject" value="<?php echo esc_html( $product->get_title() ) ?>" />
```

**Step 2**

Fetch and use the product title in conact form 7.

I have configured my form (in backend at /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpcf7) like this (the default:get is what extracts the value from the URL parameter):

```
<div>
    [hidden product-id default:get]
    [text* contact-subject default:get id:subject class:required placeholder "Betreff Ihrer Nachricht"]
</div>
```

So the URL to my contact page looks like this:

```
https://www.***.de/contact/?product-id=603&contact-subject=productTitle#contactform
```

Perhaps you can adapt my approach and modify it to your needs. (I currently do not need the add-to-cart functionality.)

Comment: This code work up to somewhere. 
This code which i have addedd on my **functions.php**
**<input type="hidden" name="contact-subject" value="<?php echo esc_html( $product->get_title() ) ?>" />** but i cant display this on the contact form :(

Comment: No no Fisnek, I think you misunderstood my approach. I will improve my answer.

Comment: Your answer works properly but i  just need a way so this function can work on my CF7 backend **<input type="hidden" name="contact-subject" value="<?php echo esc_html( $product->get_title() ) ?>" />**

Comment: @jasie Your approach is right but need to add a contact form in single page and that contact form have one text filed which is already field with current product title. This is goal.

Comment: Well, the fields in your contact form have different names: e.g. 'your-subject' in yours instead of 'contact-subject' in mine.

Answer (score 1):

**Install plugin :**

- Contact Form 7 (CF7) plugin
- Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension plugin

**Add code in contact form**

```
<label>Product Name
[dynamictext product-name "CF7_get_post_var key='title'"]</label>
```

**Custom code**

Add code in function.php in your theme.

> Note: please change shortcode of your CF7.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'dc_cf7_form_to_all_products');
function dc_cf7_form_to_all_products($content) {
    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) && is_product() && is_main_query() ) {  // Check suggested by: https://pippinsplugins.com/playing-nice-with-the-content-filter/
        return $content . '[contact-form-7 id="54" title="Demo Form"]';
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: on one page i have multiple products displayed and i use one button and one contact form and if i do [_post_title] or [_post_url] it will give me the url or name of the page and not the name of the product which the form was subbmited from
I am using this on the shop page not on product single page

Comment: Please check second way which is best suitable

Comment: I have seen that solution but it is for the Product-Single-Page
I need a solution for shop page where all the products are displayed and i don't want users to go on product page i want them to simply press a button form the shop page without visiting the product

Comment: @Fisnik I have perfectly run above code. Your requirement is fullfill.

Comment: It runs good but it gives me the shop-page name and not the product-page name if you can give me your email i will send you some pics and videos so you can see what i want

Comment: if you are on shop that is not working purpose is you just get name while in detail page

Comment: So there is no solution ?

Comment: solution is you can try with js